# Discrete diode definition

Tags: components, diodes

What is "discrete diode" and when it should be used? Google doesn't help to find the answer.

What is the difference between discrete diodes and others?

Comment: Can you give us a reference for a term discrete diode? If we see the context, it may be easier to determine the meaning.

Comment: Googling gets you better results if you are a bit creative. If "discrete diode" doesn't answer your question, maybe "discrete component" does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'discrete' just means 'in a package by itself' - as opposed to 'integrated' into a package with other components.

Answer (score 5):

I've always understood it to mean a single diode, such as a 1N4148, as opposed to multiple diodes in the same package (a diode array or bridge), or a diode that is included on an IC.